# Show that $31 | ord(\alpha)$ for a root of $f \in \mathbb{F}_{5}$

Tags: ring-theory

Let $f$ be an irreducible monical polynomial of in $\mathbb{F}_5[X]$ such that $\deg(f)=3$, and let $\alpha$ be a root in some field $\mathbb{F}_5^n$. Show that $31$ divides the order of $\alpha \in (\mathbb{F}_5^n)^*$.

---

*My own work*

The root $\alpha$ must belong to some field $\mathbb{F}_{125}$. There are $124 = 31 \cdot 2^2$ elements in $\mathbb{F}_{125}^*$. I know that $\alpha$ can't have the order $4$ or lower because the equality $x^5=x$ is a property specific to $\mathbb{F}_5$, and 
$\alpha$ does not belong to $\mathbb{F}_5$.

---

is this all right or are there mistakes in there. Please tell me.

Comment: It looks just fine to me.

Comment: There are $125$ elements in the field, you meant the group of invertible elements (I guess)

Comment: Yes I do. Thank you for noticing that.